# Improving the Page Speed on Wordpress (GT metrix and Google analytics)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, pagespeed

> Defer parsing of JavaScript

```
**JS    HIGH**
```

*What's this mean?
1.8MiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.*

> Specify a cache validator

```
**SERVER    HIGH**
```

What's this mean?
The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently. Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for the following resources:

I need your help in fixing these issues over my webpages, it seems these are the main issues that are popping up and also the fact  that we wanted to display our videos on webpage that is wordpress based, is there any way that we can go around doing the same with minimum load time.

Answer (score 0):

For the "defer parsing of Javascript" issue. You simply need to add the "defer" parameter to your script tags. You can do this with a plugin like [Async Javascript](https://wordpress.org/plugins/async-javascript/) or you can simply add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
function defer_parsing_of_js( $url ) {
     if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return $url; //don't break WP Admin
     if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
     if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
     return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $url );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 10 );
```

For the cache validator issue, the solution will be different based on whether your server is running Apache or NGINX.

For Apache, you'll need to add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>
```

For NGINX, you'll need to add the following to your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
     add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

[Source: defer parsing of JS](https://kinsta.com/blog/defer-parsing-of-javascript/)

[Source: cache validator](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/specify-a-cache-validator/)